# Unix to find pdf files from list in text file

Tags: unix, find, move

I have a directory (for Endnote) that is filled with PDF files (1000's of them). I have used Unix to print a list of all of the pdf files and saved this list as a text file. Most of these pdf files are located in other directories throughout my computer (duplicates).

Now, I want to use the find command to search for duplicates of these pdf files throughout the rest of my computer and if a duplicate is found, move it to a new directory. If a specific file name is found more than once, I want to give each a unique name (ie basename.pdf.1, basename.pdf.2 etc). At the end, I want a single directory for all duplicates so I can double check them and then delete).

However, I do not want find to search the directory in which my list was made from or my Dropbox, as I do not want to move these pdf files (only move the other pdfs scattered throughout my computer).

I have found (I think) how to do all of the individual steps that I need to complete this task, but I cannot seem to put everything together into a working Unix command.

1) In order to find files while excluding a directory:

```
find -name "what to search for" -not -path "excluded_directory"
```

or

```
find build -not \( -path excluded_directory1 -prune \) -not \( -path excluded_directory2 -prune \) -name \*.what_to_find
```

or my current favorite

```
find . -name '*.what_to_find' | grep -v exludeddir1 | grep -v excludeddir2
```

2) In order to read a text file into find and use the lines as search patterns:

```
find . type f -print | fgrep -f file_list.txt
```

3) to find and move files

```
find / -iname "*.what_to_find" -type f -exec mv {} /new_directory \;
```

or

```
find / -iname "*.what_to_find" -type f | xargs -I '{}' /new_directory
```

or (to rename files so files with same name are not just overwritten by each other). I haven't quite figured everything going on in this command out yet...

```
find -name '*.what_to_find' -type f -exec bash -c 'mv -v "$0" "./$( mktemp "$( basename "$0" ).XXX" )"' '{}' \;
```

So, I can execute this commands individually, but have not been able to get them to work together as desired (maybe my order of commands is wrong? other problems?).

```
find . type f -print | fgrep -f file_list.txt | grep -v excludeddir1 | grep -v excludeddir2 -exec bash -c 'echo mv -v "$0" "./$( mktemp "$( basename "$0" ).XXX" )"' '{}' \;
```

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks,
Derrick

Comment: there have been several questions in the past few days for very similar problems. Try searching for `[bash]|[linux] find move|rename` The `|`ed items represent unique entities. Don't try search for that exact string, you won't get anything. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well I wasn't able to complete this task exactly how I wanted to, but I found a work around that got the job done.

I printed a list of all PDFs I have in Endnote, then deleted the path name, leaving just the file names (find and replace function in text wrangler). I then used the find command to search this list against my computer, printing all occurances of each PDF.

Then in text wrangler, I deleted all lines containing the initial path to my endnote PDFs, leaving just the desired duplicates.

Next, I used the find command to search for these exact paths and move them to a new folder.

All In all, I got by with the exact same commands I have in my original post, and a little help from text wrangler. Unfortunately I never figured out how to combine all my desired steps into a single unix command.